# How do I stick the children of ListHeaderComponent in FlatList with stickyHeaderIndices property?

Tags: react-native

I get stuck in sticking the children of ListComponentHeader in FlatList (ListComponent is a View with some children components such as: banner, search bar respectively).

I have used stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} in FlatList but it would stick whole header component. While what I need is just the search bar. Does anyone have solution for this problem? Thank in advance.